# Laravel | Database seeding factory

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration, faker

I am currently learning about Laravel factories and how they work. So far I have found them really useful!

I am working on a directory for businesses so I am trying to just seed some dummy data whilst I am developing.

Currently I have got it so it creates a business along with a user, however now it's starts getting tricky which is why I am posting on here.

With the business, I also need to create categories, locations, images and contacts. I imagine they will all work in the same way so I'm only going to ask about categories.

Essentially what I want to do is when the business gets created I would like to create a category every 10 businesses, as this would then allow me to display them as they would appear in a real life situation.

So currently I have this code...

```
factory(App\Models\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {
    $u->business()->save(factory(App\Models\Business::class)->make());
});
```

This is perfect for creating the business associated to the user but where about would I put the category? Would I have to create in in here? And say every time there is a multiple of 10 then create a category? Becuase the category isn't associated to the user in anyway so I wouldn't be able to do anything like `$u->categeory` I would have to access the business model.

This is the factory for the business category...

```
$factory->define(App\Models\BusinessCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'friendly_name' => $faker->word,
        'slug' => ucfirst($faker->word)
    ]
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will each business have a category? I assume you want each business to belong to a category, but not each business to have a new category (so every ~10 business would share the same category). Is my assumption correct? Or will only 1/10 of the business actually have a category.

Comment: Your assumption is correct yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: Posted something that should get you on track. Let me know if it works. I'm not 100% sure that `$u->business()->save(...)` actually returns the Business model. If it doesn't, it won't work as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test the solution, so there might be some fine-tuning to be done, but try this and let me know if it works:

```
// Number of users
$numberOfUsers = 50;

// Will create roughly 1 business category per 10 users
$businessCategories = factory(App\Models\BusinessCategory::class, round($numberOfUsers/10))->create();

factory(App\Models\User::class, $numberOfUsers)->create()->each(function ($u) use ($businessCategories) {
    $business = $u->business()->save(factory(App\Models\Business::class)->make());
    // Associate it with a random business category
    $business->businessCategory()->attach(
        $businessCategories->random()->id
    );
});
```

**Edit**

Or you could go from the other way around and do something like this:

```
// Create 5 categories
factory(App\Models\BusinessCategory::class, 5)
    ->create()
    ->each(function ($bc) {
        // Create 10 users per business category
        factory(App\Models\User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($u) use ($bc) {
            // Create a business for the user
            $u->business()
                ->save(factory(App\Models\Business::class)->create([
                    'business_category_id' => $bc->id // Associate it with the business category
                ]));
        });
    });
```

Both solutions assume that Business belongsTo BusinessCategory. And the bottom one also assumes `business_category_id` for the foreign key column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The first method seems one that would be best suited to me however I get the error of `associate` does not exist. Going to try the second method now.

Comment: Only problem is, with the second method. It's based on creating the users & businesses. However, I would also need to do business images etc as well.

Comment: I've sussed it! Using your base of the first one, I managed to get this done! So basically, I have a `belongsToMany` relationship so `associate` does not exist. Therefore, running this line `$business->categories()->attach($businessCategories->random()->id);` does exactly what I needed!

Comment: Ah great! Makes sense, the `->associate()` would work from the other way around. My mistake. Going to edit the answer to correct that. Edit: it actually wouldn't, it would work on `belongsTo`

Comment: I'll accept it. Thanks for that, at first I didn't think it was possible, now I need to do it for the rest of the tables that I Have but now I have the basis that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I have another question though devk, can we take this to chat?

Comment: Sure, I'm just not completely sure how